# Volontary fasting rewards and tavelling

Tags: sunnah, sawm, reward

**As-Salam Alaikum**

I was wondering, if i do a voluntary fast (ie. not Ramadan) and due to traveling i would break the fast temporary for the travel time (ie more than 3 hours). Then resume the rest of the day, would i still get the reward for fasting that day?

I did try to find somethings on it, but most of the information is on Ramadan fasting and it is generally good to makeup a day of obligatory fasting.

But since this is a voluntary fast i wondered if it carried some of the same rulings?

> source would be gladly appreciated.

Also if this question falls too much into a grey area where more doubt can arise than certainty, let it go into the dark where it belongs.

Comment: Somewhat relevant [What if a person ona journey broke the fast of Ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48268/what-if-a-person-on-a-journey-broke-the-fast-of-Ramadan). Hm... my first thought is you broke the fast so this doesn't really count as fasting.

Comment: Indeed it is quite close. ty :)

Comment: When the fasting is broken, it is broken. I would not go as far as saying "it will not count", because I'm not the judge of that, maybe God will be generous. But, in Islam, the fast is considered broken.